# Format datepicker date to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to make a datepicker work. The datepicker pops up when you click a calendar icon right next to an input field. When a use clicks the icon, and selects a date, the input field should populate with the date. This works if i do not try to format the date, but as soon as i do, i get an

> 'Cannot read property "formatDate" of undefined'

The icon of a calendar has a class of '.calendar'. Here is my code for when they click that icon.

```
$('.calendar').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yy',
    startDate: '-1'
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $(this).prev('input').val(
            $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/y', ev.date)
        );
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
```

As soon as it hits

```
$(this).prev('input').val(
  $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/y', ev.date)
);
```

It stops working. What am i doing wrong here? 
If you just do `$(this).prev('input').val(ev.date);` it works perfect, but that format is wrong, and it will not go into my database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should set up a jsfiddle or at least tell us *which* datepicker you're using

Comment: This is code i have inherited, so i am not sure which datepicker they are using. i'm just trying to figure out why it is not working. and everything i try, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: how are we supposed to solve the problem? At least you have access to the datepicker plugin and can read that to find out how it works. The error is telling you that $.datepicker is undefined.

Comment: I tried building a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsstr/) but it works there. which it tells me that this should be working. but why would it not work on my program?

Comment: Looks like the fiddle was set up with jquery ui as the datepicker. Earlier you mentioned that you weren't sure which datepicker they were using. Is it jquery ui?

Comment: yes it is jquery. I ended up using [This](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) plugin to make it work. I must have had another plugin installed that was conflicting with the datepicker.dateFormat. This was just an alternative.